# Change default implementation language of a POU in TwinCAT

Tags: plc, twincat

When you create a new POU in a project, there is an option to select the implementation language. On one system the default implementation language is set to *Structured Text (ST)* and on a second system it defaults to *Continuous Function Chart (CFC)*.

[image]

I thought I once changed the default option somewhere, but I have no clue anymore where that was. I looked at the project properties and under *Tools>Options>TwinCAT*, but I can't find any option here. Does anybody have an idea where I can change the default implementation language for a POU?

Comment: I think it remembers last language you'd selected.

Comment: Thanks I think this was it. It was very strange, because on a virtual machine this setting was apparently reset somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's like Sergey mentioned.

Twincat will remember the latest selected language.

I think it is bound to the latest selected language within the specific project.